# Why App fabric distributed cache session is much faster than Appfabric DataCacheFactory GetCache?

Tags: session, azure, session-state, distributed-caching, appfabric-cache

I see significant performance difference between Session state with AppFabric Caching versus DataCacheFactory GetCache.

When I try to get some of the large objects(for example: collection of 60 items or so) using DataFactory GetCache, the time elapsed is around 50ms where as it is taking less than 1ms when custom provider "AppFabricCacheSessionStoreProvider" used in the session state.
Can anyone explain why elapsed time is much higher in DataFactory GetCache than Appfabric distributed session state and how to make it fast with DataFactory GetCache?

I have three AppFabric nodes running in a cluster.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are comparing the performance of **Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache**'s **DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider** with the default DataCacheFactory's Get method ???

By any chance **localCaching** or **isCompressionEnabled** set to TRUE in the settings when you are retrieving objects using the  Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache's DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider